# Let $e$ an idempotent element of a ring with identity $A$, then $Ae$ is a projective module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am a little confused. We have that $e \in A$ with $e^{2} = e$. I need to prove that $Ae$ is a projective module. I want to prove this with the equivalence an $A$-module $P$ is a projective module iff for all $M,N$ $A$-modules and morphims $f:Ae \to N$, $g:M \to N$ with $g$ a surjective function, there exist some morphims $h:Ae \to M$ such that $g \circ h = f$

We have that $f(e) = \alpha \in N$, as $g$ is surjective we have that there exist some $\gamma \in M$ such that $g(\gamma) = \alpha$

Then if I take for all $a\in A$, $h(ae) = a\gamma$ we have that $g(h(ae)) = g(a(h(e)) = ag(\gamma) = a\alpha = f(ae)$

Then $Ae$ is a projective module... But I didn´t use the fact that $e^{2} = e$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Is your map well-defined? Is it a module homomorphism?

Comment: Aaaah, may be not. Thank you!!!